# C# iText, signature invisible in printing

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

i use iText.kernel in c#, i create signature fields (+1 invisible signature by putting all rect properties to 0), I sign and save the pdf. when i open the pdf i see all signatures that are supposed to be visible, but when i want to print all signatures are invisible! and i don't know what's wrong with my code.

I use this code for creating signature field:

```
PdfSignatureFormField newSignField = PdfSignatureFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(pdfFieldInfos.FieldX, pdfFieldInfos.FieldY, pdfFieldInfos.FieldWidth, pdfFieldInfos.FieldHeight));
newSignField.SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.WHITE);
newSignField.SetBorderColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.BLACK);
newSignField.SetFieldName(pdfFieldInfos.FieldName);
form.AddField(newSignField, pdfDoc.GetPage(pdfFieldInfos.FieldPage));
```

And i sign with this code:

```
var pdfSignatureFieldInfos = pdfExistingSignatureFieldsInfos[i];
using (MemoryStream srcMemStream = new MemoryStream(filledPDF))
{
  using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcMemStream);
    reader.SetUnethicalReading(true); // bypass encryption

    // Open PDF in stamping mode and will be edited in append mode.
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, memStream, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

    //// Créez l’aspect de la signature.
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldX, pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldY, pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldWidth, pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldHeight);


    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
    appearance
      .SetPageRect(rect)
      .SetPageNumber(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldPage);

    if (pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldReason != null)
    {
      appearance.SetReason(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldReason);
    }

    if (pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldLocation != null)
    {
      appearance.SetLocation(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldLocation);
    }

    if (pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldSignatureCreator != null)
    {
      appearance.SetSignatureCreator(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldSignatureCreator);
    }

    if (pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldContact != null)
    {
      appearance.SetContact(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldContact);
    }                

    // If there is no image like invisible signature avoiding this part
    if (pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldValue != null)
    {
      byte[] imageBinaries = Convert.FromBase64String(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldValue);
      ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageBinaries);
      appearance
        .SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC)
        .SetSignatureGraphic(img);
    }

    if (isFirstRecipientToSign && i == 0) // The first recipient to sign and first recipient signature img => add the certification signature
    {
      signer.SetCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING);
    }
    else
    {
      signer.SetCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.NOT_CERTIFIED);
    }

    signer.SetFieldName(pdfSignatureFieldInfos.FieldName);


    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm);

    ITSAClient tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://timestamp.digicert.com", "", ""); // Setting a timestamp for signature
    signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, tsaClient, 0, subfilter);

    reader.Close();

    filledPDF = memStream.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your notes, I resolve it by using:
newSignField.SetVisibility(PdfSignatureFormField.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the signature visible, you can use the following snippet

```
newSignField.SetVisibility(PdfSignatureFormField.VISIBLE);
```